# Server.Transfer in Asp Net Core 3.1

Tags: html, url, iis, .net-core, server

I have two applications hosted and running in IIS in my windows server.

1. **App A**: Dot net core 3.1 application running on 80/443 port handling requests from external clients.
2. **Site B**: Hosted on a different port, say 32342, which has sensitive data and serving html pages.

App A is exposed to external network. Site B is behind firewall and not exposed to outside network (*Port is blocked by firewall*).

Whenever a new request comes to App A, after authentication, it should serve corresponding page from the Site B.

After searching several options, I came up with the option of Server.Transfer(). Unfortunately, it is not supported in Dot net core 3.1

I read about URL Rewrite. But it rewrites all the requests. I just need to serve contents from different server after authentication only for couple of controllers. How do I achieve this inside a Controller.?

(Other better options to serve webpages after authentication is also welcome).

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could write codes to send the request to siteB and get the response. But I still couldn't understand clearly about why you want to redirect the request. If you don't want to let the user access, you could use the application to get the data and return the data to the user instead of user directly get it.

Comment: Yes. The reason for not using redirect is that, we donot want to expose the static resources to external parties.
And since it is HTML (which has other embedded links inside it), based on user clicking the links, it again sends requests (but this time, there won't be proper end point in the controller to receive it so it returns 404). That's why i'm looking for server.transfer which sounds close to what i/m trying to achiev4e